# Mongodb field not null delete

Tags: mongodb

How do I remove all documents in a collection where a field's value isn't null? Basically the MySql query version would be like this:

```
// MySql query
DELETE FROM companies WHERE createdBy != NULL

// What I tried but did not work.
$this->mongo->companies->remove(array('createdBy' => true));
```

I don't even know if it is possible, if anyone could help me with this I would appreciate it ;)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it easy via [not equal](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$ne) operator:

```
db.companies.find( { createdBy : { $ne : null } } );
```